# How can I get the compass bearing regardless of device orientation?

Tags: android, iphone

I'm trying to create an app which requires me to find the compass bearing.

The users will hold their device so that the screen is always facing them but will be able to rotate it 360 degrees.

I can successfully determine the bearing for one orientation - portrait or landscape - but I need to find a method which will determine the bearing regardless of rotation.

Can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You should use data from gyroscope that can fully determine angles of device.
You can find this link helpful:
http://www.touchqode.com/misc/20101025_jsug/20101025_touchqode_sensors.pdf

Comment: Yes, thanks, I've got that far. However, I'm not clear how I can combine matrixR, matrixI, matrixAccelerometer & matrixMagnetic so that I always get a constant bearing, regardless of rotation. It would seem I need to remap my matrixMagnetic vector so that it's in world coordinates rather than device coordinates. And that would imply the matrixR vector. I think it's this step I'm missing.

Comment: @jFort Also some devices have magnetometer, i think you should check it first. Without magnetometer you can only appologise where is north  by current time and check images from camera for sunlight(but it's fantastic I think). Also you can ask to calebrate firstly your app manually say to place phone to the north direction, and then check accelerometer and gyroscope data. Without manual calibration everything useless in this case.